# Joomla plugin for login

Tags: php, joomla

**UPDATE:**

@Elin:

Thanks for the link! And sorry for the awful formating of my comments, I just don't make line-breaks working.
But what I try is not really to change a user. I just wanted to create it.
However, I changed my plans of what my plugin should do. Perhaps you have an idea how to make my plan working:
I explored the following:
If I have an user with username 1 with password 1 in Joomla DB and the same user with another password (this is important because otherwise the user would directly authenticate against Joomla DB) in my external DB, a login in frontend with the password from the external DB works without any problems.
A login to backend works ONLY with the password (and so with) the user in Joomlas DB, even if all details are the same (even the groups).

How can I log the user who was authenticated against my external DB into backend?!

One more time many thanks in advance!

**_____** End of update **____**

I have a (hopefully) little problem that drives me crazy:

I juste wrote a plugin for Joomla 3.1. This plugin allows an authentication against an external webserver script (with onUserAuthenticate()). Works properly.

Than I thought it was better to make backend access possible. So I wrote a second plugin to make that possible.
This plugin searches the authorized user in Joomlas DB and adds him if not found to *#__users* and *#__user_usergroup_map*. To here it works properly as well.

Now my question:

Frontend login works, backend doesn't (only a blank white page is displayed).
**Do I have to insert the user in any other tables as well?** Or is anything missing? Did I forget something?!

My code for the login plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Plugin
 * @subpackage  Authentication.External
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2014 Stefan Herzog. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

/**
 * External Authentication Plugin
 *
 * @package     Joomla.Plugin
 * @subpackage  Authentication.external
 * @since       3.1
 */

// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
class PlgUserExternal extends JPlugin
{
    /**
     * Load the language file on instantiation. Note this is only available in Joomla 3.1 and higher.
     * If you want to support 3.0 series you must override the constructor
     *
     * @var    boolean
     * @since  3.1
     */
    protected $autoloadLanguage = true;
    /**
         * This method should handle any authentication and report back to the subject
         *
         * @param   array   $credentials  Array holding the user credentials
         * @param   array   $options      Array of extra options
         * @param   object  &$response    Authentication response object
         * @param   object  $response     Authentication response object
         * @param   array   $result       Authenticataion response array    
         * @return  boolean
         *
         * @since   1.5
         */
        public function onUserLogin($user, $options = array())
        {

            // Set default values
            $allow_backend_access = FALSE;  


            if(isset($user['admin']) AND $user['admin'] === 1)
            {
                $allow_backend_access = TRUE;     // works! This parameter is delievered with $response from onUserAuthentication()
            }

            // Get a db connection.
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();

            // Create a new query object.
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);

            // Select all records from the user profile table where key begins with "custom.".
            // Order it by the ordering field.
            $query->select($db->quoteName(array('id')));
            $query->from($db->quoteName('#__users'));
            $query->where($db->quoteName('username') . ' = '. $db->quote($user['username']));

            // Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
            $db->setQuery($query);

            // Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
            $results = $db->loadAssoc();    

            if(count($results) == 0)
            {
                $checkUser = 0;
            }
            elseif(count($results) >= 1)
            {
                $checkUser = 1;
                $user_id = $results['id'];
            }

            if($checkUser === 0)
            {

                // Create a new query object.
                $query = $db->getQuery(true);

                // Insert columns.
                $columns = array('name', 'username','email','password');

                // Insert values.
                $values = array($db->quote($user['fullname']), $db->quote($user['username']),  $db->quote($user['email']), $db->quote($user['password']));

                // Prepare the insert query.
                $query
                    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__users'))
                    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
                    ->values(implode(',', $values));

                // Set the query using our newly populated query object and execute it.
                $db->setQuery($query);
                $db->query();
                $user_id = $db->insertid();

                if($user_id >> 0)
                {
                    /************* Insert user into user_usergroup_map table *************/

                    foreach($user['groups'] AS $group_id)
                    {
                        $columns    = NULL;
                        $values     = NULL;
                        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

                        // Insert columns.
                        $columns = array('user_id', 'group_id');

                        // Insert values.
                        $values = array($db->quote($user_id), $db->quote($group_id));

                        // Prepare the insert query.
                        $query
                            ->insert($db->quoteName('#__user_usergroup_map'))
                            ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
                            ->values(implode(',', $values));

                        // Set the query using our newly populated query object and execute it.
                        $db->setQuery($query);
                        $db->query();
                    }
                //$instance = $this->_getUser($user, $options);
                }
            }

            // $instance = JFactory::getUser($user_id); // works
        }
    }?>
```

Thank you for every help!

Best regards
Stefan

Comment: What happens if you put `$allow_backend_access = FALSE;` in an `else { }` statement instead. so `if(isset($user['admin']) AND $user['admin'] === 1) { $allow_backend_access = TRUE; } else { $allow_backend_access = FALSE; }`.... Also, where are you getting `admin` from in this >> `$user['admin']` ?

Comment: Moving $allow_backend_access doesn't change anything (of course, what should it change?).
And I get $user['admin'] from the method onUserAuthenticate(), where I just added the parameter. Your question brought me to the idea to unlink this parameter right after setting $allow_backend_access, but this didn't work neither. :(

Comment: Fair enough, and as asked before, where are you getting `$user['admin']` from? If you want to check if a user is an admin, use `$user->isRoot`

Comment: Ok, now I understand your question: The value of "admin" comes from my external database. So the user is not stored in Joomlas db when onUserLogin() is called the first time. Because of this I need to store it manually (with the two $query requests).

I made it this way because I can't see the method where a new user is being registered if authenticated and not available in Joomlas db yet. Can I make this more comfortable?

So I'm not able to use $user->isRoot() because the user is not an admin yet.

Comment: Do not insert directly, use the API for creating a user. Make sure you have actually studied the process of authentication and user creation.  If you want to give backend access you should add the user to a user group that has backend access.

Comment: @Elin : I did. What I'm wondering about is that even an already existing user "UserA" in Joomlas DB with PW "A", I assigned to group "BackendAllowed" can login properly, but another user "UserA" with password "B" in my external DB can't, even this user is already in Joomlas DB. He only has another password now, but username matches and authorization works?! Do you know anything about this?

Comment: The user is already in Joomla and in the BackendAllowed user group?  This group is not super admins is it?

Comment: Yes, the group is not super admin. Only backend access.

Answer (score 0):

This ones is pretty involved, lol.  A couple of thoughts to provide some direction.

Firstly, you should only need one authentication plugin to handle both front and back end authentication.  Within the authentication plugin you can identify whether the request is from the front or back-end login form by using:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->isSite();
```

and

```
JFactory::getApplication()->isAdmin();
```

Secondly, and I'm not sure if you are doing this from the you post, but you should always create a Joomla user in the DB when a new site visitor authenticates against your external DB, regardless if they authenticate in the front or back-end.

Thirdly, when creating users I would recommend letting Joomla core do all the work by creating the new user using the JUser object.  For instance, you could create and save a user doing so:

```
$user = new JUser();
$user->set('name', $columns['name']);
$user->set('username', $columns['username']);
$user->set('email', $columns['email']);
$user->set('password', $columns['password']);
$user->save();
```

Now this of course is very simplified and without any data validation or scrubbing, so you must be diligent to perform these checks within your code.

**EDIT 1**

As op pointed out, I failed to provide any feedback regarding the groups.  If you know the group id you can add it using the users helper class.  You should have the new user id in the JUser object after you execute the save:

```
JUserHelper::addUserToGroup($user->id, $group_id);
```

Good luck!

Comment: This looks quite interesting, thank you! I also came to the conclusion to let Joomla creating the user. Unfortunately your code has one "problem" (at least I think so):  
If a new user authenticates against my database, it is automatically created by Joomla and stored to its DB.  I already created a group with backend access permission. How can I tell Joomla to insert the user (from "my plugin") into exactly this group? It's defined in plugins configuration.  
Even in your code I can't set the group manually, neither I can't if I take a look at http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JUser.html.

Comment: I just explored a new problem, may be you have some helping idea:  
If I create a user in Joomla backend and assign him to the created group with backend access permission, a login in both frontend / backend works properly. If I then change the password in my external DB, a login in the frontend works, a login into backend doesn't (white page).  
Any idea why the login process is killed and not just aborted with "Wrong credentials"?
  PS: A login with the password stored in Joomla DB is working even the same username exists in my external DB but with another PW... :-/

Comment: If I try to user your code, everything except the group adding works.  
Frontend error message: "Access Usergroup Invalid"

Comment: **UPDATE**
The code is `JUserHelper::addUserToGroup($user->id,$group_id);`

Comment: **NEXT UPDATE**: I still can' access backend  with this user -> blank page. What else could I do?

Comment: What does the addUserToGroup() return?  Is the group added in the database? I'm going to update my answer with some additional information.

Comment: Also make sure you modify $config  to change the default group for new users.

Answer (score 0):

The Joomla backend has certain built in security features that make it basically much more difficult to log into the back end. For example if you have ever tried to make a REST request against the backend you will hit the white screen.  If you look at com_login in the backend you will see it is really different than the login view of com_users.  You need to basically force the process of use creation (possibily invisibly to the user) to go through the front end.  To allow admin access what you want to do is make a default user group that has the login.admin permission.  You can override that configuration setting in your plugin.

As mentioned above, you should only ever use the Joomla API to create users as it is complex, involving a number of tables plus you need to handle the encryption properly.  You might need a user plugin as well as an authentication plugin.  You may want to look at how cookie authentication works in Joomla, although it is specifically blocked from the backend.

Update

I didn't understand that you were trying to change an existing user.   If you look at the JUser code you will see that changing a user requires a session with a user that has permissions to change users .  The session you have is a session of a user who (because her groups are not changed yet) definitely does not have user edit permissions.   Further to add a super admin that session needs to belong to a super admin.  The problem is that you don't have a session.  There is a way to fake this that I used [here](https://github.com/elinw/AddUsersFromTable/blob/master/AddUsersFromTable.php#L254).  Since you actually know the id of the admin user you can hard code that even.

Update 2

Because of what I mentioned (same issue as for REST) you are going to have to have challenges.  Basically the authorization and authentication flow is different in the two applications.   In the backend you must go through the login, so your plugin really needs to simulate the login process. Notice how it is hard coded there in JApplicationAdmin. There are some plugins out there that implement basic auth for the admin and that is another possibility but only if you are using ssl in my opinion unless you are behind a fire wall 100%. Com_config does a shared session thing which could possibly be helpful.

Comment: Hi Elin, please see the update of my question. My comment was too long, so I just edited the question.